# Declaration Matched Before Assignment

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am making a parser for a programming language I'm building, and am running into an issue: ANTLR seems intent in not matching variable declarations.
Here is the grammar:

```
// Define a grammar called simc
grammar simc;

//Parser Rules
program : statement+ ;
statement : declaration | assignment | ( expression SEMICOLON ) ;
expression          : LEFTPAREN expression RIGHTPAREN                 #parenthesisExp
                    //Math
                    | <assoc=right>  expression '^' expression        #powerExp
                    | expression (ASTERISK|SLASH) expression          #mulDivExp
                    | expression (PLUS|MINUS) expression              #addSubExp
                    //Bool Operations
                    | expression EQUALITY expression                  #equalCompExp
                    | expression NONEQUALITY expression               #notequalCompExp
                    | expression GREATERTHAN expression               #greaterCompExp
                    | expression LESSTHAN expression                  #lessCompExp
                    | expression GREATERTHANOREQUALTO expression      #greaterorequalCompExp
                    | expression LESSTHANOREQUALTO expression         #lessorequalCompExp                   
                    //Any value that isn't an expression itself
                    | value                                           #valueExp
                    ;
value : constvalue | functioncall | variable ;
functioncall : IDENTIFIER LEFTPAREN expression? ( COMMA expression )? RIGHTPAREN ;
declaration : typelabel variable EQUALS expression SEMICOLON ;
assignment : variable EQUALS expression SEMICOLON ;
constvalue : intvalue | floatvalue | stringvalue | boolvalue ;
typelabel : INTLABEL | FLOATLABEL | STRINGLABEL | BOOLLABEL ;
variable : IDENTIFIER ;
intvalue : INTVALUE ;
floatvalue : FLOATVALUE ;
stringvalue : STRINGVALUE ;
boolvalue : BOOLVALUE ;

//Lexer Rules
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
LEFTPAREN : '(' ;
RIGHTPAREN : ')' ;
INTLABEL : I N T ;
FLOATLABEL : F L O A T ;
STRINGLABEL : S T R I N G ;
BOOLLABEL : B O O L ;
INTVALUE : [0-9]+ ;
FLOATVALUE : [0-9]+ ( PERIOD [0-9]+ F? | F ) ;
STRINGVALUE : QUOTE ( '\\"' | . )*? QUOTE ;
BOOLVALUE : ( T R U E ) | ( F A L S E ) ;
SEMICOLON : ';' ;
ASTERISK : '*' ;
SLASH : '/' ;
PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
EQUALS : '=' ;
EQUALITY : '==' ;
NONEQUALITY : '!=' ;
GREATERTHAN : '>' ;
LESSTHAN : '<' ;
GREATERTHANOREQUALTO : '>=' ;
LESSTHANOREQUALTO : '<=' ;
COMMA : ',' ;
PERIOD : '.' ;
QUOTE : '"' ;
fragment A : [aA] ; // match either an 'a' or 'A'
fragment B : [bB] ;
fragment C : [cC] ;
fragment D : [dD] ;
fragment E : [eE] ;
fragment F : [fF] ;
fragment G : [gG] ;
fragment H : [hH] ;
fragment I : [iI] ;
fragment J : [jJ] ;
fragment K : [kK] ;
fragment L : [lL] ;
fragment M : [mM] ;
fragment N : [nN] ;
fragment O : [oO] ;
fragment P : [pP] ;
fragment Q : [qQ] ;
fragment R : [rR] ;
fragment S : [sS] ;
fragment T : [tT] ;
fragment U : [uU] ;
fragment V : [vV] ;
fragment W : [wW] ;
fragment X : [xX] ;
fragment Y : [yY] ;
fragment Z : [zZ] ;
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
COMMENT : ( ( '/' '/' .*? ( '\r'|'\t'|'\n' ) ) | '/*' .*? '*/' ) -> skip ;
```

The grammar should, if I'm not mistaken, match the code `int a = 5;` as a declaration of a variable. Instead, I get an empty statement (which I don't understand how that particular event is possible,) a statement marked as incorrect containing the int text (in my testing, it only worked for valid type names) and a correct assignment. To my best understanding, declarations should be found before assignments, right? Why does it match like this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the tokens generated for your input, you'll see that it sees `int` as an `IDENTIFIER`, not an `INTLABEL`. This happens because you've defined `IDENTIFIER` before `INTLABEL` in your grammar and when multiple lexer rules can match the same amount of input, it will use the one that comes first in the grammar. Therefore you should always define your identifier rule *after* the keywords.

Comment: Thanks you, this was correct. I do have to ask, do you know why I got an additional empty statement before the assignment?

Comment: @Zombie_Pigdragon That's just how the error handling algorithm works out, I guess. I don't really know, sorry.